# Eventhandler for WPF control in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've been working with WPF and I have experienced a problem related with DataTemplates.
I have a view called **DetailPage.xaml** and this view uses a DataTemplate called **Detail.xaml**. I added a textbox to this DataTemplate and I want to handle the TextChanged event. So I made something like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="DetailContent">
    <Grid Margin="5" DataContext="{Binding Items[0]}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="80"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Width="432">
            <TextBox Name="NumeroParadaTB" Text="{Binding NumeroParada}" MaxLength="5" TextChanged="NumeroParadaTB_TextChanged" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then I created and event handler in **DetailPage.xaml.cs**, like the following:

```
protected async void NumeroParadaTB_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string nroParada = ((TextBox)sender).Text;

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nroParada) && nroParada.IsDigitsOnly() && nroParada.Length == 5)
        {

        }
    }
```

But when running, and error is thrown saying that the event handler doesn't exist. I guess I'm using the eventhandler in a wrong way.

Thanks!

Comment: Why to handle `TextChanged`, if you're using data binding? Why don't just handle `NumeroParada` property changing in data context?

Comment: Sorry Dennis, I'm a noob in WPF. Do you have an example that could help me to achieve that?

Comment: Do you want to validate entered text value and display validation results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using data binding, I assume, that you have some class with `NumeroParada` property:

```
public class SomeClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /* other code here */

    public string NumeroParada
    {
         get { return numeroParada; }
         set
         {
             if (numeroParada != value)
             {
                  numeroParada = value;
                  OnPropertyChanged("NumeroParada");
             }
         }
    }
    private string numeroParada;    
}
```

Setter of this property will fire, when UI will update the binding source. This is your "`TextChanged`" event.

Note, that by default, `TextBox` updates `Text` property, when loosing focus. If you want to perform any action when user changes text, update your binding definition:

```
Text="{Binding NumeroParada, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

So far so good. But this code:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nroParada) && nroParada.IsDigitsOnly() && nroParada.Length == 5)
```

suggests, that you're trying to implement validation of value, entered by user.
Validation in WPF is rather big theme, I'd recommend you to read something like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714593.aspx) to select validation approach.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding an Event handler, you can use Event to Command logic. Create a Command in ViewModel and bind it to the TextChanged event.

```
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBox>
```

Interaction triggers available in System.Windows.Interactivity assembly.

Comment: While there are reasons to use interaction triggers, this is definitely not the case. It is not necessary to perceive this question literally.